# Plot 2^x function

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to plot the function y = 2^{x} with tikz. My code is

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\datavisualization
[
    school book axes, 
    visualize as smooth line=one, 
    y axis={label={$y=2^x$}}, 
    x axis={label},
    one={style={blue}}
]

data [format=function]
{
    var x : interval [-1.5:1.5];
    func y = 2^(\value x);
};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The problem is that this code represents strange shapes when x < 0.

How can I fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: Works fine here as well, can you make a complete example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` (similar to what Sebastian did in his answer) and show a screenshot of the output you get?

Comment: Even using exp(x*\log(2)) it should work fine for negative x (but not -2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works correctly for me!

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\datavisualization
[
    school book axes, 
    visualize as smooth line=one, 
    y axis={label={$y=2^x$}}, 
    x axis={label},
    one={style={blue}}
]

data [format=function]
{
    var x : interval [-1.5:1.5];
    func y = 2^(\value x);
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Comment: I have executed the code in a newer texlive package version and it run perfect.

Thanks